# jQuery Validation Plugin, phoneUS field is breaking form

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-validate

I've been working on a simple form using the jquery validation plugin for browser-side validating, and for some reason unbeknownst to me it seems like the 'phoneUS' rule seems to be breaking the rest of the validation code.

So long as that field ("tel") is blank on the form, the validation works as intended.  But if anything is entered into the telephone field (including letters), then the validation is skipped and the form is submitted, even if other required fields are left blank.  However, if the 'phoneUS' rule is taken out of the code, other validation rules applied to the 'tel' input still apply.  Needless to say, I'm thoroughly confused.

The script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#survey1').validate({
    rules: {
    firstname: {
            required: true,
            },      

    lastname: {
            required: true
            },

    address1: {
            required: true
            },

    city: {
            required: true
            },      

    state: {
            required: true
            },  

    zip: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
            },  

    tel: {
            required: true,
            phoneUS: true
            },  

    email: {
            email: true
            }

   }



   });
});

</script>
```

the labels and input fields are just simple text boxes with names matching the script.  The form action is set to use a php file to email the results to a static e-mail address.  If any other information would be helpful, I'll provide it.

I'm relatively new to jQuery, so feel free to offer pointers (superfluous characters, etc.).

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your request for pointers.  I see no syntax errors on first glance, but suggest that you properly indent the code for easier reading and debugging.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery Validate does not come with the `phoneUS` function standard; you have to add it.  Before your `$('#survey1').validate()` code, call this function:

```
// Add US Phone Validation
jQuery.validator.addMethod('phoneUS', function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ''); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, 'Please enter a valid phone number.');
```

Comment: FYI, it does not matter if place `addMethod()` before or after `.validate()`.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/AFpaC/

Comment: Aha!  It seems so simple now... but thank you a million times over for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 7):

You need to include the [`additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) which contains the `phoneUS` rule/method.

Alternatively, if you'd rather not include an another JavaScript file, you can manually add just the `phoneUS` rule/method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(\+?1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/AFpaC/**

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This is incredibly helpful.