# How to create the multiple form field with same name using single form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select#select_btn').change(function(){
 
    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
 if(sel_value==0)
 {
  //Resetting Form 
  $("#form_submit").empty();
  $("#form1").css({'display':'none'});
 }
 else{
  //Resetting Form 
  $("#form_submit").empty();
  
  //Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically 
     create(sel_value);
  
  //appending submit button to form
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<input/>",{type:'submit', value:'Register'})
  )
  } 
 }); 
 
function create(sel_value){
   for(var i=1;i<=sel_value;i++)   
    {
    $("div#form1").slideDown('slow');
    
     $("div#form1").append(
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<div/>",{id:'head'}).append(
  $("<h3/>").text("Registration Form"+i)),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Name', name:'name_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Mobile', name:'mobile'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Email'+i, name:'email_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
  //$('select').append($('<option>', {value:1, text:'One',name:'city',placeholder:'City'+i})),
  $("<hr/>"),
  $("<br/>")
                  ))
     }
 
 }
 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/multipleform.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div class ="container">
   <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="Name" />
    </p>
    <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="player_email" />
    </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="mobile" />
    </p>
     <p> Refer:

<div id="selected_form_code">
 <select id="select_btn">
 <option value="0">--Select No Of Form to Display for Registration--</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 <option value="4">Four</option>
 <option value="5">Five</option>
 </select>
 </div>

 <div id="form1"> 
  <form id="form_submit" action="#" method="post">
   <!-- dynamic Registration Form Fields Creates here-->
  </form>
 </div> 
<!------ right side advertisement div ----------------->

 
</div>
</body>
```

I am creating a Form with multiple form fields and i need to validate all the form fields. I put the validation but it is not working properly.
It validates 1st data and stop the validation.

When i select `Refer` as 1 it shows the following Form field

1. Name
2. Mobile
3. Email
4. City
5. Course

If i select 2 means it should show the form field two times, with validation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in your javascript. In order for validation to work you need some code similar to the following

```
$(function() {
  jQuery.validator.addMethod('phoneUS', function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
      phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
  }, 'Please enter a valid phone number.');

  $('#form_submit').validate({
    rules: {
      Name: "required",
      player_email: "required",
      mobile: {
        required: true,
        phoneUS: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      Name: {
        required: "Please enter your name"
      },
      player_email: {
        required: "Please enter your email"
      },
      mobile: {
        required: "Please enter your phone number",
        phoneUS: "Please enter a valid US phone number"
      }
    }
  })
})
```

The call to `jQuery.validator.addMethod()` is necessary because the validator doesn't have a phone number validator by default. (See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16652933/1362086))

You should also reverse your script tags because the jQuery Validation Plugin depends on jQuery.

Try

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

To make the dynamic fields work add the inputs to form:

```
<div id="input">
  <input type='text' name='hide1'/>
  <br>
  <input type='text' name='hide2'/><br>
  <input type='text' name='hide3'/><br>
  <input type='text' name='hide4'/>
  <br>
  <input type='text' name='hide5'/>
</div>
```

Then you can hide them in jQuery with `$('#input input').hide();`.
You can use jQuery to reveal the fields and add validation to them on the change event of the select element (See the [plugin documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/)). You could try

```
  $('#select_btn').change(function() {
    var val = $('#select_btn').val();

    if (val > 0) {
      $('input[name=hide1]').show().rules('add', {
        required: true
      });
    } else {
      $('input[name=hide1]').hide().rules('remove');
    }
    if (val > 1) {
      $('input[name=hide2]').show().rules('add', {
        required: true
      });
    } else {
      $('input[name=hide2]').hide().rules('remove');
    }
    if (val > 2) {
      $('input[name=hide3]').show().rules('add', {
        required: true
      });
    } else {
      $('input[name=hide3]').hide().rules('remove');
    }
    if (val > 3) {
      $('input[name=hide4]').show().rules('add', {
        required: true
      });
    } else {
      $('input[name=hide4]').hide().rules('remove');
    }
    if (val > 4) {
      $('input[name=hide5]').show().rules('add', {
        required: true
      });
    } else {
      $('input[name=hide5]').hide().rules('remove');
    }

    $('#input>input:hidden+label').hide();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i need to show the form field when i select refer??? How can i do this

Comment: @user2454624 You want to show as many additional inputs as indicated by the select?

Comment: @user2454624 I edited my answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: It was not working. I need the form like this https://www.formget.com/create-multiple-form-fields-based-on-selection-jquery/

Comment: I create the Form but i need create select field using append after email. How to do it .....

Comment: @user2454624 It's the same concept. You can create any number of inputs that can be displayed or hidden as needed with JavaScript or jQuery. You can also add and remove validation rules from each input.